# remove index.php from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using Ubuntu. and server is also linex. And my frame is codeigniter.
My `.htaccess` code is working on local but not on server..
I am using .htaccess for removing index.php 
My Server Url is like `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/foldername/index.php/signup` . Here xx.xxx.xxx.xxx is http_host.

My .htaccess code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

i have set in config in `$config['index_page'] = '';`

This all code is woking on localhost. but on server its not working.

Please tell me how to remmove index.php from url ?

Comment: Your url is `/index.php/signup` ?? Normally index.php is configured as the default file after index.html, so just try to remove index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your `/foldername/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /foldername/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

then in `/foldername/application/config/config.php` you need to have these config settings:

```
$config['base_url']     = '';
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```